# Where does my C Wire go?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

[image: Wiring showing C Wire]

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Changing thermostat and need to connect c wire at furnace. I connected to the brown bundle based on the wiring diagram and it worked to get power to the new thermostat. However, only the the fan runs when trying to cool. No cold air comes out. Not sure what else needs to be done.

Comment: Lets start with what system do you have ? one stage or two stage cool/heat, with our without heat pump,  for that use the model number and look it up

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram of your air handler please?